# Update of snap-store snap caused Ubuntu Software to disappear

Tags: .desktop, ubuntu-store

On one installation of 20.04, `snap refresh` caused the snap-store snap to be updated, which made the orange "Ubuntu Software" icon disappear, and in its place is the "Snap Store" with a different icon. Same thing happened on another installation when updating "Snap Store" through the store itself.

[image: The Snap Store icon]

How can I restore the original orange icon and "Ubuntu Software" label?

Answer (score 0):

If your system still has this problem, the way to fix it is to run `snap refresh snap-store --channel=stable/ubuntu-20.04`